# I am having a 32 bit OS, 2 Gb ram and intel core 2 duo processor

Tags: windows-7, windows

I do not have Virtualization Technology in my pc and I want to use it so that I can improve the speed of my memu app player. Can you please tell me any way so I can speed up my emulator without buying anything new for my pc.I have windows 7 starter.

Comment: Your PC is simply inadequate for what you're trying to use it for. There is no magic solution that will make it a capable PC.

Comment: Its a... 10 year old PC - and windows 7 starter only shipped with netbooks, so I'm not quite sure how that PC got that OS. At the end of the day though there's only so much performance you can eeke out of the old girl without upgrades. In this case fairly major ones.

Comment: So what do I need to enable VT in my pc.

Comment: buy a new PC. VT is a hardware feature of the CPU. You can't magically implemented it in software

Comment: So how can I speed my memu emulator or please tell any other emulator which do runs fast without Virtualization technology

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about ["Memuplay"](http://www.memuplay.com/blog/2016/01/27/system-requirements/) an android application emulator for Windows your system just barely fits the requirements.

To enable VT you'd need to check your BIOS. With your specific system configuration it's likely that you're using a netbook or similar and that the option is simply not available. There are Core 2 Duo that do have VT but especially on netbooks you usually don't. If the hardware feature is not available no option can be enabled and if the hardware feature is available the option has to be available for you to do anything.

The recommended CPU on the page above would be a i5-8400, an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 and 16 GB of RAM. Your system configuration is so far from it that's likely easier to get a cheap Android phone to have better performance.